# Pydev: execute a file in the console

Tags: pydev

Is it possible to get pydev in eclipse to run a file in its console?

Example of what I would like to do:
1. hit ctrl-alt-enter
2. select console
3. open a python file
4. somehow run it in the console
5. inspect the results

Comment: I don't think I follow: Ctrl+At+Enter does execute a file in the console: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html (you just have to open it first -- and if you already have the console open, it'll execute it in the existing console)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to open a console. See this page for a how-to: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html

You then have two choices:

`>>> runfile(r'/path/to/my/file.py')`

or

`>>> execfile(r'/path/to/my/file.py')`